# ghc: can't find a package database

Tags: haskell, ghc

Im trying to run the ghci REPL but this happens

```
# ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghc: can't find a package database at /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
```

when trying to list installed modules:

```
# ghc-pkg list
ghc-pkg: /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

when trying to install openFile:

```
# cabal install openFile
cabal: ghc-pkg: /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d: openFile: does not exist (No such
```

file or directory)

Comment: The 'openFile: …' output is an error describing that there is no file under /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d that ghci can read. It looks likely that your ghc installation is broken.

Comment: This is the same answer I'd give if your Python site-packages was corrupted: reinstall.  I'd use this as an opportunity to upgrade to the latest haskell platform version.